# whl packages for python 3 in `pypi.python.org`

Tags: python-3.x

There is no whl packages for python 3 in in `pypi.python.org`

for example,twisted package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/17.5.0

there  is only `Twisted-17.5.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`,
I want the version for python 3.6,
how to get it?

Comment: Ask the maintainers to publish one?  Or clone the repo and make one yourself.

Comment: You don't even need to clone the repo. See https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ Try just running ``pip wheel Twisted`` and it should create a wheel file.

Comment: That's wheely cool.  Didn't know this feature of pip before :)